# AngularJS Directive Template dont execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a Problem with my AngularJS Directive named "showFileBrowser". I want to use Javascript in my Template but it will not be execute in my Browser. Here is my Code:

```
app.directive("showFileBrowser", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<script>$("#searchNote").fileTree({data: scope.filedata,sortable: false,selectable: false});</script>'
    }
});
```

Someone know why I cant execute Javascript in a Directive or know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use the id, use 'element' directly.

```
app.directive("showFileBrowser", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {    
          $(element).fileTree({data: scope.filedata,sortable: false,selectable: false});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice with the element parameter. But still it dont work.

Comment: you console may have fired errors, like a problem with filedata because i failed, it's `$scope.filedata` and not `scope.filedata`. try to put console.log to help you

Comment: No my console dont show anything. It look like everything works fine. My answer show you one method that works.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if I return a function, but i prefer return an Object.

```
 app.directive("showFileBrowser", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        $(element).fileTree({data: scope.filedata,sortable: false,selectable: false});
   }       
});
```